# Get distance between the entity anchor and the camera

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I'm adding a scene to my `ARView` that contains one entity. I was wondering how I would be able to get the distance between the entity's anchor and the camera. I know how to get the current position of the camera, but the position I'm getting for the `arScene` must be wrong since subtracting both positions doesn't yield the right position. Here is some code below.

```swift
import RealityKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSessionDelegate {
  let arScene = try! TestProj.loadScene()
  @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    sceneView.scene.addAnchor(arScene)
    ...
  }

  func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    // Calculate distance here
    let cameraPos = frame.camera.transform.columns.3
    let entityPos = // Position of entity's anchor
    let distance = // Find distance here
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean as the position of the scene? What you’re actually adding is an Entity with HasAnchor (AnchorEntity). if you’re adding many entity children to it, do you want the bounding box centre of all these children, or just the position of the AnchorEntity?

Comment: Position of the Anchor Entity, I'll update my question thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to perform a `Convex Raycast` against all the geometry in the RealityKit's scene for a ray between two end points:

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let entity = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: 0.4))
        entity.name = "Cube"

        let anchor = AnchorEntity(world: [0,0,0])
        anchor.addChild(entity)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
    
        // For every entity that could be hit,
        // we must generate a collision shape.
        entity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
    }

    @IBAction func onTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        let query: CollisionCastQueryType = .nearest
        let mask: CollisionGroup = .default

        let camera = arView.session.currentFrame?.camera
        let x = (camera?.transform.columns.3.x)!
        let y = (camera?.transform.columns.3.y)!
        let z = (camera?.transform.columns.3.z)!

        let transform: SIMD3<Float> = [x, y, z]
           
        let raycasts: [CollisionCastHit] = arView.scene.raycast(
                                                           from: transform, 
                                                             to: [0, 0, 0], 
                                                          query: query, 
                                                           mask: mask, 
                                                     relativeTo: nil)
    
        guard let raycast: CollisionCastHit = raycasts.first
        else { return }
    
        print(raycast.distance)     // Distance from the ray origin to the hit
        print(raycast.entity.name)  // The entity that was hit
        print(raycast.position)     // The position of the hit
    }    
}
```

Also, as @maxxfrazer suggested, you can access camera transforms more easily:

```
let translate = arView.cameraTransform.translation

let x = translate.x
let y = translate.y
let z = translate.z

let transform: SIMD3<Float> = [x, y, z]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not returning any raycasts. For more clarity, I created an entity in Reality Composer and am loading the .rcproject inside Xcode. I can add the scene to my ARView but then inside the session(didUpdate frame:) method, where I placed you code, raycast is always nil. I think you're on the right track though. I hope we can solve this :)

Comment: Have you generated collision shapes?

Comment: Yup I generate collision shapes right before adding the anchor to arView

Comment: I got it! I just had to increase the `to:` parameter to include the entity so it would also include the entity that was placed on a horizontal plane. I'll mark your answer as right.

Comment: You can just get camera transform with `let transform = self.cameraTransform.translation`, no need to get the optional currentFrame and force unwrap it

Comment: Thank you @maxxfrazer, I added it.